# Seperate the jars using maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to separate the jars into different folders.

Inside my project, I have several modules, i.e: module1, module2, and assembly.

By using maven assembly plugin, I would like to put generated jar from modules1 and module2 into target/modules and all the dependencies into target/dependencies.

How can I achieve this requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that your project is structured like :

```
project
    |- module1
    |- module2
    |- assembly
        |- pom.xml
        |- src
            |- assembly
                |- bin.xml
```

`assembly` should depend on `module1` and `module2`; set these dependencies in `assembly/pom.xml` :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You must also add `maven-assembly-plugin` in `assembly/pom.xml` :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`assembly:single` is bound on `package` phase, to create the assembly when running `mvn package`.

Finally, define `assembly/src/assembly/bin.xml` as follows :

```
<assembly   xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>modules</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>${project.groupId}:*:*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
            <outputDirectory>dependencies</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>${project.groupId}:*:*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

- `format` defines the format you want for the assembly (here a directory, but could be `tar.gz`, `zip`, ...)
- first `dependencySet` defines a folder `modules/` where all artifacts from the same `groupId` will be put. Here you can also control if you want only some of the artifacts (for example if you want only `module1`). `assembly` JAR is excluded from this folder, as this module is only used to create the assembly
- second `dependencySet` defines a folder `dependencies/` where all dependencies (and transitive dependencies) will be put. Dependency here means *artifact with a different `groupId`*, as states the `excludes` clause

`mvn package` will then generate the assembly (in `assembly/target/` folder), named `assembly-${project.version}-bin`, with the structure you want.